# Automatically set posts to NoIndex depending on category?

Tags: plugins, posts, categories, seo, noindex

I'd like all new posts with a specific category to automatically have NoIndex applied.

There are various plugins - e.g. Wordpress SEO - which make it easier to manually select posts for NoIndex. But I can't find a way of automating the process.

Comment: What is the question? if you are looking for plugin recommendations, they are off-topic here.

Comment: Am not looking for a plugin recommendation (although it may be that a plugin is required to enable this). I want to to know how to automatically set posts to NoIndex based on their category. i.e. if a post is category "X" then automatically set to NoIndex

Answer (score -3):

1) Go to post categories.

2) Click on 'edit' of the target category.

3) Scroll down and there will 2 options to select indexation option of all posts in that category and whether to include in sitemap.

Update as you want and BINGO!

Comment: Are you sure about that? That sounds like a plugins function to me.